# Fetching error when using core data

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data

I am relatively knew to Core Data, and when running the below code an error occurs:

## Code:

```
let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
var loadedSources = [Sources]()

do {
    loadedSources = try context.fetch(Sources.fetchRequest())
} catch {
    fatalError()
}
```

## Error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'NSFetchRequest could not locate an NSEntityDescription for entity name 'Sources'
```

## Question:

However, Sources is the name of my entity in my data model, so I am unsure why this exception is occurring. Besides this exception, I have no runtime errors. I going about fetching in the wrong way?

Comment: Set the NSFetchRequest and you'll be Ok

Comment: Are you sure your xcdata model is in the right target ?

Comment: What is fetchRequest() doing ?

Comment: Please paste the code where you are creating the managed object context

Comment: please show a screensot of  *.xcdatamodeld file in xcode

Answer (score 0):

### Check:

Check if the `managedObjectContext` has a valid `persistentStoreCoordinator`. If not then that is the problem

```
print("persistentStoreCoordinator = \(managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator)")
```

### Posible solution:

Set the `managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator`

### Explanation:

- Managed object model contains all the entity descriptions (entity name, attributes, class used for the entity etc)
- Managed object context is like a scratch pad, where you can make changes to the records.
- Persistence coordinator coordinates with the different stores, managed object model and provides managed object context a unified view of the data.
- If the managed object context doesn't have a valid `persistentStoreCoordinator` then then the managed object context wouldn't be able to get the entity description from the model.

### Reference:

- https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DataManagement/Devpedia-CoreData/coreDataStack.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010398-CH25-SW1
- https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DataManagement/Devpedia-CoreData/persistentStoreCoordinator.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010398-CH27-SW1